# Any issues occured when unnecessary files importing in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Hi I am developing iphone/ipad Applications. I took one header.h and import all `ViewControllers` importing in that header.h. Then i just import header.h in all classes.

Like `header.h` contains

`#import "loginViewController.h"`

`#import "signupviewController.h"`

and i have imported #import `header.h` in all necessary `view-controllers`.

if i done like this, any memory issues occurred or not?

I know, in C language, if we done like above, all unnecessary code have to be included, What about in objective-c?

I googled, but i didn't find the required answer.

please tell any one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#import` keeps track of which headers have already been included and is ignored if a header is imported more than once in a compilation unit.

This makes it unnecessary to use header guards.

The `#import` line is only replaced by the contents of name file for the first time it is encountered.

The bottom line is just use `#import` in `Objective-C` and don't worry if you are importing headers more than once.
`#import` ensures that a file is only ever included once so that you never have a problem with recursive includes. But that is not the same case with #include.

Answer (score 0):

You should only import the headers you need. Let's say you have view controllers 1 - 10. What you have done only makes sense if every view controller needs every other view controller. This is unlikely.

This will also slow down compilation. Every view controller will end up compiling the header file of every view controller. Why bring in all of that unneeded detail?

What you are doing won't use any more memory but it is a waste of compiler time and it's not self documenting. By having each class only import what is needed, you can better see the actually dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can easily acces this type of header file like a **constant**  file like bellow..

this is my `constant.h` file which is **Objective-C protocol** template (file). i just import this file and i access all file and keys which i define in this file...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "yourViewControllers.h"
...etc....
/// you can also use some APIKey globally 

@protocol constant <NSObject> 

@end
```